# Remove duplicate class imported into Enterprise Architecture

Tags: reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

I'm having the same problem as describe in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974836/enterprise-architect-how-to-synchronize-with-source-code-source-model-when).

I'm struggling to remove the duplicate classes (hundred of) as I can't delete all and import again since all the sequence diagrams will be affected. I use EA 6.5.

Comment: _'I use EA 6.5'_ This is a very outdated version (current is 10), I think the solution (local path variable) explained in the answer is available since version 7.5 or higher.

Comment: Local path variable won't help if duplicates are already there. And they are quite hidden away so it is to expect that everybody will make the mistake at least once and only then switch to use local path variables.

Using the physical hard-drive path instead of the logical class package is a fundamental flaw of the application.

Comment: @g-makulik: My organization uses this version, I have no choice to upgrade it.